# Why aren't Java package vulnerabilities fixable with a single patch?

Tags: java, security, import, package

I have zero experience with Java, but when trying to understand a certain "apocalyptic" vulnerability, I ended up with a fundamental question about `import`s in `Java`, so please bear with me.

My question is, as given in the title, why a `Java` package can not be updated with a single central patch.
For comparison, two hypothetical diametric cases that I think I understand reasonably well:

- If, say, a `python` library had some vulnerability, then it should suffice (on well-maintained systems that use centralized libraries located on `PYTHONPATH`) to update that single library and any code that `import`s it should, in general, be fixed.
- On the other hand, if a `C` library had a vulnerability, then it would be necessary to replace every single binary whose source `include`s the vulnerable library with a patched binary.

Now, as far as I could tell, `Java` is actually closer to the former category of languages, where external `import`s are not included in compiled sources.
If this is the case, then why can't a single patch be applied to fix an entire system (au contraire, our IT department forwarded [a gigantic list of software](https://gist.github.com/SwitHak/b66db3a06c2955a9cb71a8718970c592) for us to check individually)? Is it because of multiple decentralized copies of identical libraries being installed, or is there some other reason? Or am I misunderstanding the issue?

Comment: Using patches is awful and obsolete. It's better to use a newer version, since you can then test that the problem has been fixed.

Comment: *"Is it because of multiple decentralized copies of identical libraries being installed"* Indeed. Every Java application comes with its own set of libraries (.jar files).

Comment: @JustanotherJavaprogrammer Oh, sorry, my use of the term patch was very loose. I was including updated versions of the library (in fact, that's what I had in mind).

Comment: I think you have a big mish-mash of terms. Well-written C code doesn't import executional code, only header. Imports in Java are more like namespaces, they don't actually import anything or link anything - that's done at the link phase of compilation. You can reference a library without importing it. And even if you patched libraries, many Java apps stay alive for weeks and wouldn't reload the jar anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Java applications themselves are separate processes. In principle, all these processes can use different VM's. This is often the case for larger applications, which are tested against a specific VM. In principle, Java runtimes (J2SE implementations) should remain as compatible as possible with each other, but it is certainly possible for developers or libraries to muck this up, e.g. by using "Sun" inner classes or by assuming things not specified for the API calls. Personally hate these kind of J2SE inclusions; I'd rather have applications that are created to remain compatible.

Smaller applications usually just run on one of the installed JRE's. However, they usually still need *additional* libraries or components - say, for instance, Log4J from Apache. These are often offered as separate .jar files (or "artifacts" in Maven speak). These libraries may also get updates; there is however not a common way of updating these on most systems; there is no single "application" set of shared libraries although it is certainly possible to create one. On Linux for instance there may be a set of libraries in `/usr/share/java` (by version, with generic names pointing to the latest one).

Many web applications - I those running on a specific application server such as Tomcat, Glassfish etc. do share a common "classpath", where application specific .jar files are put in specific folder. In that case an update of a library in the shared folder will affect all applications.

Java has had a framework for specific class-loaders, and in principle any framework can define their own set, so where the libraries are stored can depend on the framework. Java is very flexible and doesn't really have one single way of handling applications.

---

All this has previous little to do with `import` statements. These are just use as a shorthand notation, basically. You might as well use `java.util.List` as `import java.util.List` followed by `List` further in the code. Class files contain references to other classes (etc.), and those are resolved (found and loaded) **at runtime**; see the description from Oracle [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/findingclasses.html).